# login to yahoo email account using Python Selenium webdrive

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, yahoo

I need to login to yahoo email account using Selenium with Python.

this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com")

print driver.current_url

logintxt = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
logintxt.send_keys("email")

pwdtxt = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")
pwdtxt.send_keys("pass")



button = driver.find_element_by_id("login-signin")
button.click()
driver.get("https://mail.yahoo.com")
print driver.current_url
```

but when I print the current url, it always gives me the login page, which mean that it didn't login.

any idea about how to fix it ?
I'm using Centos 6 with python 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for it (using `WebDriverWait`) to redirect you to the `yahoo` main page on successful login before navigating to the Yahoo mail box:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

button = driver.find_element_by_id("login-signin")
button.click()

# give it time to log in
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url == "https://www.yahoo.com/")

driver.get("https://mail.yahoo.com")
```